# numa allocated memory is shared from two forked processes?

Tags: c, unix, memory-management, shared-memory, numa

I am using NUMA api and I need to do what can be done by the `mmap()` using the `MAP_SHARED` flag, i.e: a process allocates memory and after that, it forks. I need that this allocated memory will be shared from the two processes. If P1 modify this memory region. this modification is seen by P2 and vice-versa. How can I do with `numa_alloc_onnode()` function?

Thank you

Comment: You probably should point to the online manual page for the function, because the function is not standard.  Reading the manual page will probably give you the answer. If it doesn't say how it _can_ be done, it probably can't be done.

Comment: Do you mean ``numa_alloc_onnode``?

Comment: yes sorry, I mean numa_alloc_onnode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a two step process for setup:

1. `numa_alloc_onnode()` - allocates the memory on the specified numa node.
2. `mmap()` - maps the specified memory to a file, including the ability to share the memory between processes.

In other words, mmap() will work the same with memory that was allocated via `malloc` as memory that was allocated via `numa_alloc_onnode`.